# How can i create push_back function of dynamic array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Im trying to create this and add push back functionality. How can i do it? I came up with this code but im very confused for 2 days because it gives this output - *| -842150451 | -842150451 | -842150451 | -842150451 | -842150451 | -842150451 | -842150451 | -842150451*
I will be thankful if someone can tell me how this function push_back should look or at least point me in the right direction. Also i would be thankful if you tell me where this code is doing wrong?

```
 struct IntArray{
private:
    int k;

    int* first_cell;

    int size; // currently occupied elements
    int capacity = 8; // size of the allocated memory

public:
    void create() {
        first_cell = (int*)malloc(capacity * sizeof(int));
    }

    void random_numbers_fill(int limit) {

        srand(time(NULL));

        for (k = 0; k < capacity; k++) {

            first_cell[k] = rand() % limit;
        }

    }

    void push_back(int number) {

        if (size == capacity) {
            int* new_arr;
            capacity *= 2;
            new_arr = (int*)malloc(capacity * sizeof(int));
            for (k = 0; k < capacity; k++) {
                new_arr[k] = first_cell[k];
            }
            free(first_cell);
            first_cell = new_arr;
            first_cell[size] = number;
            size++;
        }

    }

    void print() {
        for (k = 0; k < capacity; k++) {
            printf("| %d ", first_cell[k]);
        }
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] including expected vs. actual output. Also read this: [ask]

Comment: @Jabberwocky Im asking for the push_back function how it should work because im confused how it should work.

Comment: `-842150451` looks like your compiler is trying to tell you something. That number is the same as `0xcdcdcdcd` which is uninitialized heap memory on Visual Studio: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations)

Comment: [Here's a handy list of common debugging codes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Debug_values). In general when you see weird-ass number, convert it to Hex. If you get something highly repetitious or a pattern that's unlikely to not be by design like a word or phrase, check to see if it means something special

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `create()` should be changed into an actual constructor.  And you are missing a destructor to free the array, as well as copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators to manage the array (per the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)).

Second, you should be using `new[]` instead of `malloc()`.

Third, regarding your `push_back()`, it is not a bad attempt, but it is buggy.  You are not adding the `number` to the array at all if the current `size` is less than the current `capacity` (and your constructor is not initializing `size` at all).  And when you do resize + copy the array, you are copying too many `int`s from the old array.  The old array is `size` elements, but you are trying to copy the newly increased `capacity` elements from it.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

class IntArray{
private:
    int* first_cell = nullptr;
    int size = 0; // currently occupied elements
    int capacity = 8; // size of the allocated memory

public:
    IntArray()
    {
        first_cell = new int[capacity];
    }

    IntArray(const IntArray &src)
        : size(src.size), capacity(src.capacity)
    {
        first_cell = new int[capacity];
        std::copy_n(src.first_cell, size, first_cell);
    }

    IntArray(IntArray &&src)
        : first_cell(src.first_cell), size(src.size), capacity(src.capacity)
    {
        src.first_cell = nullptr;
        src.size = src.capacity = 0;
    }

    ~IntArray()
    {
        delete[] first_cell;
    }

    IntArray& operator=(IntArray rhs)
    {
        IntArray temp(std::move(rhs));
        std::swap(first_cell, temp.first_cell);
        std::swap(size, temp.size);
        std::swap(capacity, temp.capacity);
        return *this;
    }

    void push_back(int number)
    {
        if (size == capacity)
        {
            int new_cap = capacity * 2;
            int* new_arr = new int[new_cap];
            for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k) {
                new_arr[k] = first_cell[k];
            }
            delete[] first_cell;
            first_cell = new_arr;
            capacity = new_cap;
        }
        first_cell[size] = number;
        ++size;
    }

    void print() const
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k) {
            std::cout << "| " << first_cell[k] << " ";
        }
    }
};
```

That being said, you should just get rid of your manual array and use `std::vector<int>` instead, as it handles all of these details for you, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class IntArray{
private:
    std::vector<int> vec;

public:
    IntArray()
    {
        vec.reserve(8);
    }

    void push_back(int number)
    {
        vec.push_back(number);
    }

    void print() const
    {
        for (int number : vec) {
            std::cout << "| " << number << " ";
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `size` in `create`.

Your `push_back` has two problems. You don't copy the number that is pushed unless you grow the array (the last two statements should be outside the `if` block), and the condition in the `for` loop should compare with `size`, not `capacity`.

`print` also has the wrong condition in the `for` loop.